# POWER BI : I want DAX formula to find out the 1st highest and 2nd highest value for a group in my Main Table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Below are my two tables , I want the 1st and 2nd highest amount from my main table through DAX,  So that I can get the Desired table with two different column , one having first highest for Sydney and Brisbane and another having 2nd highest for the same cities

[image: Main Table]

[image: Desired table]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68289548

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Table 2 =
VAR _1 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        _t,
        "rank", RANKX ( ALLEXCEPT ( _t, _t[City] ), CALCULATE ( MAX ( _t[val] ) ),, DESC )
    )
VAR _2 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        FILTER ( _1, [rank] = 1 ),
        "City", [City] & "",
        "firstHighest", [val] + 0
    )
VAR _3 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        FILTER ( _1, [rank] = 2 ),
        "City", [City] & "",
        "secondHighest", [val] + 0
    )
VAR _4 =
    NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN ( _2, _3 )
RETURN
    _4
```

[image: Source]

[image: Solution]